# Достаточно ли указать в listview - IsPullToRefreshEnabled что бы получать перезагрузку страницу при свапе вниз?

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

достаточно ли указать в listview - `IsPullToRefreshEnabled = "True"` что бы страница при проведение пальца вверх по экрану могла перезагрузиться? Нужно ли еще какой-то код на C# писать для реализации?

Answer (score 0):

Указать `IsPullToRefreshEnabled="True"` не достаточно

Нужно указать в настройках шаблона, пример на С#:
`IsPullToRefreshEnabled="True"` так понял остлеживает смахивание вниз

`listView.Refreshing += Refresh;` указывает какой метод нужно выполнять при смахивание пальцем по экрану вниз
Теперь создайте метод

```
public async void Refresh(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            listView.IsRefreshing = true;//отображает иконку загрузки
            listView.ItemsSource = await App.Database.GetItemsAsyncB();// здесь загружаете ваш контент снова у вас здесь может быть другой код.
            listView.IsRefreshing = false; // выкл. иконку загрузки

        }
```

:)